# JPA: auto loading of child objects doesn't work as expected

Tags: jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have the following two entities:

```
class Role {
  @Id Long id;
  @Column String email;
  String role;
  @ManyToOne User user;
}

class User {
  @Id Long id;
  @Column(unique=true) String email;
  String password;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  @OrderBy("role asc")
  List<Role> roles;
}
```

The SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
EMAIL VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, 
PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), 
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
CREATE TABLE ROLE (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
EMAIL VARCHAR(255),
ROLE VARCHAR(255), 
USER_ID BIGINT, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER(ID)
)
```

The following JUnit fails on the second last line.  I get the user (the parent) automatically loaded from the child, but I don't get the children automatically loaded from the parent.  What have I done wrong?

```
    Role r = em.createQuery("select r from Role r where r.email = :email", Role.class)
            .setParameter("email", "john@google.com")
            .getSingleResult();
    assertEquals("registered", r.role());
    assertEquals("john@google.com", r.user().email());

    User u = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email", User.class)
            .setParameter("email", "john@google.com")
            .getSingleResult();

    assertEquals("john@google.com", u.email());
    assertEquals("asdf", u.password());

    assertEquals(1, u.roles().size()); FAILS HERE!!!
    assertEquals("registered", u.roles().get(0).role());
```

I'm using EclipseLink 2.3.2 (JPA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways in which you can tell how the other and of a relation should be loaded. One is at the query level, using fetch join, something like this:

```
select u from User u left join FETCH u.roles r where...
```

The other is at the relation declaration level, something like this:

```
class User {
  @Id Long id;
  @Column(unique=true) String email;
  String password;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @OrderBy("role asc")
  List<Role> roles;
}
```

The reason why when you load a Role you also get the user without any special annotation or join in your query is that ManyToOne relations in JPA have fetch=EAGER by default:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#fetch()

while one to many have fetch=lazy by default:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch()

Comment: If I modify Role to also have FetchType.EAGER, it makes no difference.  As it is, the way I understand it, and the way it used to work with Hibernate, LAZY just means that the SQL to fetch the children isn't executed until you call the getRoles method.  The proxy intercepts that method call and executes the SQL and injects the data into the returned collection.  No?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. The trick is that the proxy (actually the Hibernate/JPA wrapper) will only be able to do this if the session that was used to fetch it is still open. If not you'll get the dreadded lazy initialization exception. Not to mention that using Lazy fetching is a classic example of n+1 selects (a select is made for each lazyly initialized relation). If you ask me, the best thing to do is eager-fetch all the data you need at query time.

Comment: Well I might be missing something here, but the way I see it you have a ManyToOne relation that gets loaded and a OneToMany relation that doesn't get loaded on the fly, with default configuration. This is pretty much how they should behave according to the docs. In order to have your JUnit test pass, i.e. have your OneToMany relation get loaded when you fetch the root, you have to do some extra work.